# npm OracleDB installation failed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to connect to Oracle DB using nodejs ,Below is the sample code snippet .

```
oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : "hr",
    password      : "welcome",
    connectString : "localhost/XE"
  },(function(err){
        if(!err) {

          console.log("Database is connected ... \n\n");  
        } else {
             console.log(util.inspect(conString,false,null ));      
          console.log("Error connecting database ... \n\n"+client);  
        }
    }));
```

I am getting below error  "Error: Cannot find module 'oracledb'" and tired to install Oracle module using `npm install oracledb` but failed to install : Below is the error i am getting

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:114:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\n
-gyp\lib\configure.js:69:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:95:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_m
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\UOC_UCAATM\script_new\node_modules\oracledb
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Could anyone please let me know how to resolve this issue.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "oracledb"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! oracledb@1.0.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@1.0.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the oracledb package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracledb
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\UOC_UCAATM\script_new\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: `Can't find Python executable "python"`. It means you need python to install that module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install oracledb giving error : Cannot find $OCI\_LIB\_DIR/libclntsh.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669569/npm-install-oracledb-giving-error-cannot-find-oci-lib-dir-libclntsh-dylib)

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar error and I reinstalled python 2.7 to solve it. Had to be 64-bit since I was running 64-bit OS and Oracle XE.

https://www.python.org/downloads/

Be sure to add it to your path when you install, also.

Answer (score -1):

When in doubt read the manual: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instwin
As @x4rf41 said, you are missing a pre-requisite.