# npm install oracledb giving error : Cannot find $OCI_LIB_DIR/libclntsh.dylib

Tags: node.js, oracle, npm, node-oracledb

I am trying to install `oracledb` driver on my mac using npm. I have followed each and every step mentioned in the given [link](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instosx). When I am trying to install the `oracledb` package: `npm install oracledb` I am getting the following error

```
> oracledb@1.12.2 install /opt/oracle/instantclient/node_modules/oracledb
> node-gyp rebuild
node-oracledb ERR! Error: Cannot find $OCI_LIB_DIR/libclntsh.dylib
node-oracledb ERR! Error: Do you need to run 'cd $OCI_LIB_DIR && ln -s libclntsh.dylib.* libclntsh.dylib'?
node-oracledb ERR! Error: See https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instosx
gyp: Call to 'INSTURL="https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instosx"; ERR="node-oracledb ERR! Error:"; if [ -z $OCI_LIB_DIR ]; then if [ -f /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.dylib ]; then echo "/opt/oracle/instantclient/"; else echo "$ERR Cannot find /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.dylib" >&2; echo "$ERR Do you need to run 'cd /opt/oracle/instantclient && ln -s libclntsh.dylib.* libclntsh.dylib'?" >&2; echo "$ERR See $INSTURL" >&2; echo "" >&2; fi; else if [ -f "$OCI_LIB_DIR/libclntsh.dylib" ]; then echo $OCI_LIB_DIR; else echo "$ERR Cannot find \$OCI_LIB_DIR/libclntsh.dylib" >&2; echo "$ERR Do you need to run 'cd \$OCI_LIB_DIR && ln -s libclntsh.dylib.* libclntsh.dylib'?" >&2; echo "$ERR See $INSTURL" >&2; echo "" >&2; fi; fi;' returned exit status 0 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:305:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.1.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /opt/oracle/instantclient/node_modules/oracledb
gyp ERR! node -v v7.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/oracle/instantclient/package.json'
npm WARN instantclient No description
npm WARN instantclient No repository field.
npm WARN instantclient No README data
npm WARN instantclient No license field.
npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "oracledb"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! oracledb@1.12.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@1.12.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the oracledb package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs oracledb
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracledb
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/oracle/instantclient/npm-debug.log
```

My node version is `v7.0.0` and my npm version is `v3.10.8`. Can somebody let me know as to what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [install doc](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instosx).  In summary:

1. Install XCode
2. Install Instant Client
3. Create the sym link used by Instant Client 12c
4. Set OCI_LIB_DIR and OCI_INC_DIR to the Instant Client directories
5. Set http_proxy if you are behind a firewall
6. Run `npm install oracledb` If using sudo, you  probably need to run `sudo -E npm install oracledb`

To help diagnose your issue, show us the log of the steps you tried.

Comment: With node-oracledb 2.x you should put the Instant Client 'Basic' or 'Basic Light' package in ~/lib.  There is no need for the Instant Client SDK.  There is no need for OCI_LIB_DIR or OCI_INC_DIR.  With recent 'npm' versions you may need to set https_proxy.